# Why does my Android app only produce a black screen on my phone?

Tags: java, android

I've been doing the Google developer.android.com course and I've run into a bit of a hiccup. Namely, I've finished the Android fundamentals 01.2 Part A, but made some modifications to the code such that I would have two buttons and screens for counting, and one button for showing text. I'm a beginner when it comes to Android stuff so any help is appreciated.

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1A237E"
    tools:context="com.example.android.hellotoast.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/POTATOCOUNT"
        android:layout_width="434dp"
        android:layout_height="149dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="160dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
        android:background="#1B9288"
        android:text="@string/potato_count"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="120sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ready"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/GRAVYCOUNT"
        android:layout_width="434dp"
        android:layout_height="149dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="160dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="92dp"
        android:background="#1B9288"
        android:text="@string/gravy_count"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="120sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gravyUp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/potatoUp"
        android:layout_width="436dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="160dp"
        android:text="@string/add_potatoes"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:onClick="addPotato"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gravyUp"
        android:layout_width="436dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="160dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:text="@string/add_gravy"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:onClick="addGravy"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ready"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="160dp"
        android:text="@string/ready_to_go"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/POTATOCOUNT"
        android:onClick="showDinner"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
    <string name="potato_count">0</string>
    <string name="gravy_count">0</string>
    <string name="add_potatoes">POTATO</string>
    <string name="add_gravy">Gravy</string>
    <string name="ready_to_go">ready</string>
    <string name="ready_message">BON APPETIT</string>
</resources>
```

And here is my Java code:

```
package com.example.android.hellotoast;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.myapplication.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int mcount1=0;
    private int mcount2=0;
    private TextView showmcount1;
    private TextView showmcount2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        showmcount1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GRAVYCOUNT);
        showmcount2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.POTATOCOUNT);
    }

    public void showDinner(View view) {
        Toast dinner = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ready_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        dinner.show();
    }

    public void addGravy(View view) {
        mcount1++;
        if(showmcount1!=null){
            showmcount1.setText(Integer.toString(mcount1));
        }
    }

    public void addPotato(View view) {
        mcount2++;
        if(showmcount2!=null){
            showmcount2.setText(Integer.toString(mcount2));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I've completed all the steps but there is nothing on the Android Developing site to help me fix this issue and the IDE doesn't show any errors either!

Comment: Any reason you're using the `style/Theme.NoDisplay` theme? I actually have never seen it before, but it's name seems like it is meant to produce no display...?!

Comment: It was the answer for another SO question that I thought might solve the problem (without it, the screen is still black), but it changed nothing so I left it like that.

Comment: I've now removed this to avoid confusion.